# Cordova build on windows platform overrides appxmanifest file

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8.1

I am using a different **package name** as configured in my `config.xml` for my windows platform target.

For example, this is my `config.xml` (here package name is the **id element** in the widget tag) in my root project folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="de.myapplication.mobile" version="1.1.1" ...>
```

And my `package.phone.appxmanifest` file in my windows platform folder (here the package name is the **Name** element in the Identity tag) contains for example this:

```
<Package ...>
    <Identity Name="de.myWindowsApplication.mobile" Publisher="XXX" Version="1.0.0.0" />
</Package>
```

Now building my windows platform target with `cordova build windows` replaces the **Name** element string `de.myWindowsApplication.mobile` with the id element string  `de.myapplication.mobile` from the config.xml.

(How) Can i prevent this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am sorry, not yet.